# Not able to compare two releases report in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am creating a powerbi report where we can see the comparison of different releases response time.

For that I should be able to select two release version in the dropdown.

Below is the picture of the schema:
[image]

I want to select the new and the old release in the dropdown and based on that the response time of the release should be compared

I am using the below measure for calculation and I want to remove constant from them

```
AVERAGEX(
    SUMMARIZE(
        FILTER(
            'public response_time',
            'public response_time'[release_id] = 23
        ),
        'public response_time'[sample_name],
        'public response_time'[average]
    ),
    [average]
)
NewReleasePct90 = 
    CALCULATE(
        AVERAGE('public response_time'[pct_90]),
        FILTER(
            'public response_time',
            'public response_time'[release_id] = 23
        )
    )
OldReleaseAverage = 
    AVERAGEX(
        SUMMARIZE(
            FILTER(
                'public response_time',
                RELATED('public release'[release_id]) = 22
            ),
            'public response_time'[sample_name],
            'public response_time'[average]
        ),
        [average]
    )
OldReleasePct90 = 
    CALCULATE(
        AVERAGE('public response_time'[pct_90]),
        FILTER(
            'public response_time',
            RELATED('public release'[release_id]) = 22
        )
    )
```

Something like below:
[image]

Comment: Use `MIN('public response_time'[release_id])` for the first and `MAX('public response_time'[release_id])` for the last.

Comment: But one single table response time contains the response time of multiple product a and its release.

Comment: What field are you filtering in those slicers? (New/Old Release) Maybe you should go with a disconnected/parameter table approach instead

Answer (score 0):

If you want two slicers then you will need to have a second table for the releases.

Create a new Calculated Table with (this will only be used by the New Release slicer):

```
public release (new) = 'public release'
```

Add a similar relationship from `'public product'` to `'public release (new)'`. You won't need (don't add) a relationship from the new table to `'public response_time'` table.

Then update your measures with:

```
OldReleaseAverage = 
  AVERAGEX(
    SUMMARIZE(
      'public response_time',
      'public response_time'[sample_name],
      'public response_time'[average]
    ),
    [average]
  )

OldReleasePct90 = 
  CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE('public response_time'[pct_90])
  )


NewReleaseAverage = 
  var newReleaseSlicer = MAX( 'public release (new)'[release_id] )
  return
    CALCULATE(
      [OldReleaseAverage],
      REMOVEFILTERS('public release'[release_id]),
      'public response_time'[release_id] = newReleaseSlicer 
    )

NewReleasePct90 = 
  var newReleaseSlicer = MAX( 'public release (new)'[release_id] )
  return
    CALCULATE(
      [OldReleasePct90],
      REMOVEFILTERS('public release'[release_id]),
      'public response_time'[release_id] = newReleaseSlicer 
    )
```

Comment: The problem I am facing is that the slicer value is not passed to the DAX. I want to provide both old and new release version.

Comment: The above should capture the slicer value for the NewRelease (via `var newReleaseSlicer`). And for the OldRelease it should be handled via the relationship. Old Release slicer should be from `'public release'[release_id]` and the New Release slicer from `'public release (new)'[release_id]`. If still not working, provide a link to a sample PBIX (via OneDrive, GoogleDrive, DropBox etc...) and I can take a look.